# how to add router/middleware to feathers app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, router, feathersjs

I have added a router to my feathers app as follows

```
app.use('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: 'Hello world from Express middleware'
   });
});
```

app is running at http://localhost:3030/ when I send get request to http://localhost:3030/test from postman I get following error

```
{
    "name": "NotFound",
    "message": "Page not found",
    "code": 404,
    "className": "not-found",
    "data": {
        "url": "/test"
    },
    "errors": {}
}
```

how can I fix this? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: replace `app.use` with `app.get` so the endpoint will be available by HTTP GET http://localhost:3000/test

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: could You please append the JS file where You start the server itself?

Comment: also have You restarted the server after the actual change?

Comment: Also see this FAQ: https://docs.feathersjs.com/help/faq.html#i-always-get-a-404-for-my-custom-middleware

Comment: Why are you doing Express-style middleware in a Feathers app?

Comment: @Joe can you please let me know if there is any other way

Comment: I guess it depends on your use case but app level hooks are the feathers thing. The middleware approach is IMO a holdover from Express as a rest provider and does not work for socket comms

Answer (score -1):

I think your code should be :

```
  app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: 'Hello world from Express middleware'
   });
});
```